# How to leave a blank page through Response.BinaryWrite()?

Tags: asp.net, stream

I am using .NET Reponse.BinaryWrite() method to get Byte[] values in the code and generating it as a pdf file. I need to leave an empty page at a certain page. Is it possible to do so?

```
 protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;
        string[] streams;
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] warnings;

        Byte[] reportDoc;
        Response.Clear();
        switch (Request.QueryString["report"].ToString().ToLower())
        {
            case "rpt_penetrantlog":
            case "rpt_proccdbyregion":
            case "rpt_ordersbycustomeranddate":
            case "rpt_hold":
                reportDoc = rptviewOzark.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
                Response.ContentType = mimeType;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Report.xls");
                break;
            default:
                reportDoc = rptviewOzark.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                break;
        }

        Response.BinaryWrite(reportDoc);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

The report is pulled from the SQL server

Comment: Is the PDF one that you created in your own code, or is it a pre-existing file?

Comment: I am creating it from reports (.rdlc file) through Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

Comment: `Response.ContentType` is irrelevant. What matters is what code creates the bytes. You're doing it for RDLC. How? Show your code. Perhaps you can modify the report definition to include a blank page. Or perhaps you can take the bytes it generates, then open them up with a tool such as iTextSharp, make your changes, and generate new bytes.

Comment: @mason Edited the question now

Comment: @mason I am getting from rdlc reports and rendering it here. What I wanted to do is to add a blank page as a second page when a certain condition is met. What my company wants me to do is to leave an empty page only after the first page since they are printing it two-side. The content is in tablix group and I somehow need to add an empty page only after the first page/ first group item (there are lots of group items coming from SQL).

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with RDLC to tell you if there's a built in way to add blank pages. But the iTextSharp way should work, but that should only be something you try if there's no built in way.